# Andengine get pixels from RenderTexture when game pauses

Tags: android, andengine, fbo

Here is the situation, I need to save the pixels from a `RenderTexture` and store them into a  `Bitmap` when the game activity pauses (home button was pressed), and restore  the render texture with the Bitmap that was saved.

Currently I'm doing the following:

In `onPause` register a `Draw Handler` to the engine that calls `getBtimap()` on the render texture, then call R`enderSurfaceView.reqestRender()` method, to force redraw and then `Thread` sleep for 1 second, to ensure that drawing will happen, and then finally call `super.onPause()`.

I think this is not a good method :).

The problem is that `RenderTexture.getBitmap()` have to be called in the render thread because is calling `glReadPixels()` which needs a GL context to be executed properly.

So is there anyway to get notified before the GL context is destroyed ?

Or any suggestions on how this could be done in a different way ?